# SQLite restrict a connection from doing certain actions

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am building a program that has to use sqlite connection.
i want to restrict this connection so with the connection the program using it wouldn't be able to do read operations(such as select) and it wouldn't be able to delete columns,tables and databases.

i am using c# and the System.Data.SQLite library to access the database

Is there a way that i can restrict a sqlite connection from the ability of doing certain actions?

Comment: What programming language and what library are you using?

Comment: @Tichodroma 
i am using c# and the System.Data.SQLite library to access the database

Comment: The only supported restriction I know of is the `Read Only=True` flag in the connection string. It is quite uncommon to allow delete operations but not read operations, but I'm not completely sure it's impossible.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis i want to allow the connection just the ability to write to the database but not doing anything else

Comment: Is there really even any point?  Unless you're allowing execution of arbitrary SQL code, you restrict what can be done via the functionality of the application.  If you don't want the user to be able to read any data then don't execute any `SELECT` statements.  Permissions like you're talking about would usually be handled at the server level by big databases like SQL Server, Oracle or MySQL.

Comment: @omer12433 I didn't mean to provide `Read Only=True` as an answer, I just commented that I know sqlite _has_ an access restriction parameter, just not the one you want.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the part of the application that uses SQLite is a user defined function(the user writes a function that do uses the database and my program uses this function) and i want to restrict the user from doing anything but writing so he would mess with the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 1.0.89.0, System.Data.SQLite has experimental support for the [authorizer callback](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/set_authorizer.html).

Use the `Authorize` event of the `SQLiteConnection` object.